# Hide next button on last Dialog modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML look like this

```
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                    
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset> 
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                   
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                    
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to hide the next button of last **fieldset** of every modal dialog appears. Anyone, please suggest me. I am new to jquery and haven't done this kind of thing before. I code to learn and sometimes I fall in problem.

Comment: Please post some working fiddle

Comment: i didn't find out any fiddle

Comment: I think you should rework your approach - eg use tabs to cycle between the different steps in a wizard like approach. But since you are doing this way - why do you include the next button on the last .modalDialog at all? - you could simply not include it in the html and problem solved. I would also sugggest that you have a singel form not three -and also that you include previous buttons to allow navigation backwards as well.

Comment: Add attribute `style="display:none"` to the element which you want to hide or add a class `hide` to your element and  `.hide{display:none;}` in your stylesheet. There is not need of jQuery if you don't want any action without an event.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul css answer is correct but if you gonna use jquery here is the code

```
$(".modalDialog button:last-child").hide();
```

Comment: i edited my code again. firstly i inputed wrong html. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
simple way In CSS code

```
button {
visibility: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide btn in last element use "[last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)" selector

```
.modalDialog:last-child .btn.btn-next {
    display: none;
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3nbujra/)

Comment: it's not working. this code hides the last fieldset's next button only. but i want to hide every fieldset's last next button hide

Answer (score 0):

The `:last-child` selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent, so you can select the last `form` element and hide it using `display:none`.

You can [read more about :last-child here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Notes: you are using duplicate id (id="outerr") in your HTML, which could make you markup invalid and create some issues, please consider correcting this issue in your real app.

```css
.modalDialog:last-child form {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                    
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset> 
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                   
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="" class="modalDialog">
<div>   
    <form role="form" class="registration-form" >    
        <fieldset>
            <div id="outerr">
                <div class="innerr"><button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>                    
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be.

```
fieldset:last-child .btn.btn-next {
    display: none;
}
```

this is the code which solved my problem.